# Session timeout in Angular if user is idle in canActivate function of AuthGuard

Tags: angular, session, session-timeout, auth-guard

Currently in the application if user is not authenticated then he cannot proceed to any routes but if he/she is authenticated then navigation is possible. This is implemented through canActivate function in auth guard. If I want to have a session timeout as well if user is idle suppose after 5 minutes, then what is the way of achieving that through canActivate function and Auth-Guard?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
 export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the token based communication with the api, Create token with expiration time. Use the below library for token communication

`npm install --save @auth0/angular-jwt`

And use the Auth service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // Check whether the token is expired and return
  // true or false
  return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
 }
}
```

And the change the canActivate method as below

```
canActivate(): boolean {
if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

**Edit**

Either you can use token or cookies. Code is as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

@Injectable()
export class AuthCookie {
constructor() { }

getAuth(): string {
    return Cookie.get('id_token');
}

setAuth(value: string): void {
   //use for 5 minuts, Cookies value set seconds to days, 5/1440
    Cookie.set('cookie_token', value, 0.003472);
}

deleteAuth(): void {
    Cookie.delete('id_token');
}
}
```

[see here Cookies vs Token](https://www.code-sample.com/2017/10/angular-4-5-cookie-vs-token.html)

Comment: How can we set the expiration? As I only want expiration if user is idle for some time.

Comment: But this will I think timeout after 5 minutes even if user is interacting. I want if user is not interacting with the website for 5 minutes then only expiration should happen.

Comment: You can use refresh access token which will more useful for your scenario.